# Highlight Value in a HTML Select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I highlight selected value from a multiple html select tag with data from the  database?

```
 <select required name="PrevOptns" id="PrevOptns" size="7" multiple class="select_with_label_wide"><option id="Avoid mosquito bites">Avoid mosquito bites</option>
                        <option id="Get protection from traditional healer">Get protection from traditional healer</option>
                        <option id="Other">Other</option>
                        <option id="Don't know">Don't know</option>
                    </select>
```

And below is my j query script for pulling data from the database :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "database/Emarps/websrvc/websrvc.php?task=getData&UUID=" + currentuuid + "&DataGt=hk",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (response) {

                $('#PrevOptns option[value=' + response[0].prev_optns + ']').attr('selected', true);
            }
        });
```

How can I highlight/select from the html select tag based on the returned value from the  database?

Answer (score 0):

Make each option have a value attr (`<option value="something">`), and then use `$('#PrevOptns').value();`

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

```
$('#PrevOptns option[value=' + response[0].prev_optns + ']').prop('selected', true);
```

or using **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
$('#PrevOptns option[value=' + response[0].prev_optns + ']').attr("selected","selected");
```